# Using ember-simple-auth when the login page is on another system

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

The page to login to our application is a jsp hosted on another machine.  I have managed to get requests firing to this machine by modifying `authenticated-route-mixin` by allowing `window.location.replace` to be called if the route start with http.

```
  beforeModel(transition) {
    if (!this.get('session.isAuthenticated')) {
      Ember.assert('The route configured as Configuration.authenticationRoute cannot implement the AuthenticatedRouteMixin mixin as that leads to an infinite transitioning loop!', this.get('routeName') !== Configuration.authenticationRoute);

      transition.abort();
      this.set('session.attemptedTransition', transition);
      debugger;
      if (Configuration.authenticationRoute.startsWith('http')) {
        window.location.replace(Configuration.authenticationRoute);
      } else {
        this.transitionTo(Configuration.authenticationRoute);
      }
    } else {
      return this._super(...arguments);
    }
  }
```

This is working but when I am redirected back to my application, ember-simple-auth thinks I am no longer logged in and redirects be back to the remote machine, which then sends me back to the application in an infinite loop.

Obviously I need to set something to let ember-simple-auth know that it it is actually logged in.  Why is it not doing this automatically? What am I doing wrong?

I am pretty new to oAuth so I could be missing some basic setting here.

Here is the URL.

```
  ENV['ember-simple-auth'] = {
    authenticationRoute: 'https://our-server.com/opensso/oauth2/authorize?client_id=test-client-1&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fsecure'
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying the `AuthenticatedRouteMixin`, I'd recommend handling your app-specific login in an **Authenticator**-- the key configuration primitive that [Ember Simple Auth provides as part of its public API](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#how-does-it-work).

To the best of my understanding, on first loading the app, and checking to see if a user is authenticated, Ember Simple Auth will use the `restore` method, defined as part of the Authenticator API.

You can return a promise from `restore` that resolves or rejects to indicate whether the user is authenticated. How you check this is an implementation detail of your auth system.

I don't know how you're storing credential(s) on the client (would be great if you could provide more detail), but here's an example flow, using cookies for authentication:

1. Ember boots, ESA attempts to `restore` the session.
2. `restore` makes a simple AJAX request to a secured, "dummy" resource on your Java server-- and checks if it gets back a 200 or a 401.
3. We get a 401 back. The user isn't authenticated, so reject in the Promise returned from `restore`.
4. Let ESA redirect the user to your authentication route. Ideally, don't override the `AuthenticatedRouteMixin`-- instead, use the `beforeModel` hook in the authentication route to send users to your JSP login page.
5. The user correctly authenticates against the JSP form.
6. In its response, your Java server sets some kind of encrypted, signed session cookie (this is how it generally works with Rails) as a credential. In addition, it sends a redirect back to your Ember app.
7. Ember boots again, ESA calls `restore` again.
8. `restore` pings your Java server again, gets a 200 back (thanks to the cookie), and thus resolves its Promise.
9. ESA learns that the user's authenticated, and redirects to the 'route after authentication'.

Keep in mind that, at its core, ESA can only indicate to the client whether the backend considers it 'authenticated' or not. **ESA can never be used to deny access to a resource**-- only to show something different on the client, based on the last thing it heard from the backend.

Let me know if any of that was helpful.